# C++ program to remove all spaces of a sentence from user input

Tags: c++, loops, c-strings, removing-whitespace

I would like to write a C++ program to accept user input a sentence and remove all spaces. There are bugs.

input:`ad jq jjwjfwwf`

output:`ad▀jq`

input: `dadad fff`

output: `dadad`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//using while loop to copy string
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char c[30];
    char cc[30];
    char ccc[30];
    cin.getline(c,30);
    while (c[i]!='\0')
    {
        cc[i]=c[i];
        i++;
    }
    cc[i]='\0'; 
    for (j=0;j<i;j++){
        if (c[j]==' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (c[j]=='\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        ccc[j]=c[j];        
    }
    ccc[j]='\0';
    cout<<cc<<'\n'<<ccc<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value do you think `ccc[j]` holds when you skip over a space? (You need two counters.)

Comment: This seems like the perfect opportunity to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your program line by line while monitoring variables and their values. That will make it very easy to see when and where things go wrong.

Comment: You are overcomplicating it. The problem is trivial to solve. Just read input into a `std::string` then use something along the lines of `std::erase(std::remove_if(... std::isspace(..` and you are done.

Comment: Yeah, like above, the erase/remove idiom and `std::string` have this done in <10 lines. The call to `std::cin.getline()` appears incorrect, as it doesn't allow the null character to be inserted if someone tries to fill the entire array. It also seems like you would never need three C-strings to do this. You can do it in the original array if data preservation is not a goal, or two (the original, and the modified).

Answer (score 6):

You are trying far too hard. C++ has classes and library code that do this for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;          // a string for the sentence
    getline(std::cin, s);   // get the sentence from the user
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end()); // remove the spaces
    std::cout << s << '\n'; // print the result
}
```

As you can see, if you use the `std::string` type then removing all the spaces is a single line of code.

And even if you are trying to practise writing loops, you should still be using `std::string` instead of a `char` array.

Comment: I left out the `std::` before `remove` on the grounds that it would be found by ADL (same as `getline`). Did I get that wrong?

Comment: Both will get found by ADL but `std::remove` is in `<algorithm>` and it works by chance (read: because of internal includes) even without it iff qualified- https://godbolt.org/z/Ko1hsTnqz . So that is maybe what @JesperJuhl tried to fix.

Comment: With C++20 we got an even more simplified [`std::erase(s, ' ');`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2)

Answer (score 2):

It is very inefficient to define three character arrays to remove spaces from a string.

At least the array `cc`

```
char cc[30];
```

is in any case redundant.

In fact you are not removing spaces from a string. What you are doing is copying a string from one character array into another character array without spaces contained in the string.

In this for loop

```
for (j=0;j<i;j++){
    if (c[j]==' ')
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (c[j]=='\0')
    {
        break;
    }
    ccc[j]=c[j];        
}
```

you need to use a separate index for the character array `ccc`. Otherwise it will contain indeterminate values that correspond to spaces in the array `c`.

Pay attention to that usually when spaces are mentioned then they are meant two types of characters: the space character `' '` and the tab character `'\t'`.

You could use standard algorithm `std::remove` or `std::remove_if` shown below.

However if you want to write yourself a similar algorithm for C strings then you could write a function the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

char * remove_blanks( char *s )
{
    char *src = s, *dsn = s;

    do
    {
        if (not std::isblank( ( unsigned char )*src ))
        {
            *dsn++ = *src;
        }
    } while (*src++);

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "\t1 2\t\t3   4    ";

    std::cout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';

    std::cout << std::quoted( remove_blanks( s ) ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
"       1 2             3   4    "
"1234"
```

If your compiler does not support C++17 then instead of using the manipulator `std::quoted` you could write for example

```
    std::cout << '\"' << s << "\"\n";
```

Also instead of this if statement

```
 if (not std::isblank( ( unsigned char )*src ))
```

where there is used the standard C function `isblank` you could just write

```
 if (*src != ' ' && *src != '\t' )
```

If to use standard algorithms then it will be enough to include headers `<algorithm>`, `<cstring>` and `<cctype>` and to write either

```
std::remove( s, s + std::strlen( s ) + 1, ' ' );
```

or

```
std::remove_if( s, s + std::strlen( s ) + 1, 
    []( unsigned char c ) { return std::isblank( c ); } );
```

Here is one more demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "\t1 2\t\t3   4    ";

    std::cout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';

    std::remove_if( s, s + std::strlen( s ) + 1, 
        []( unsigned char c ) { return std::isblank( c ); } );

    std::cout << std::quoted( s ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
"       1 2             3   4    "
"1234"
```

Comment: `<ccyupe>` -> `<cctype>`?